# Why is "it" used in "How is it life after death?"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, difference, articles, pronouns

Why is "it" used in "How is **it** life after death?"?  I know it looks strange, but I can't understand the use of "**it**".
Why can't I write "How is life after death?" or "How is **the** life after death?"
There are difference between the meaning of these forms?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Look up "dummy subject" ...

Comment: I've never personally heard that phrase, and google isn't giving me anything. Is the question asking "What's the afterlife like?"?

Answer (score 2):

It would probably help a lot if we set the first part of the sentence off with a comma (this is the only way to make proper sense of it):

> How is it, life after death?

To me, this sounds like somebody died and then came back to life (movie [*Flatliners (1990)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatliners) comes immediately to mind) and now one of his friend is asking them that question. This is the same as saying "*What is life after death like?*"

Answer (score 0):

In spoken language, you yould pause a bit after **it**. This makes the sentence more clear. On written language, one can (and probably should) include a comma or dash.

> How is it, life after death?

or

> How is it - life after death?

You could also simply say

> How is it? Live after death, I mean.

The second clause simply elaborates what **it** refers to.